# Maven Circular property definition

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, circular-reference

New to maven, but getting over the frustrating learning curve....

I have a simple pom file that reads a properties file and writes out a configuration file.  I use the 'properties-maven-plugin' with

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
    <id>read-install-properties</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
           <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
    </phase>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

....
....
When I add a line like this in my properties file:

```
C = ${A} + ${B}
```

and run mvn mvn install -f pom2.xml -DA=1 -DB=2

I see this in my output file:

```
C = 1 + 2
```

As I would expect.

When I change the line to be

```
C = ${A} + ${B} + ${B}
```

I would expect to see this:

```
C = 1 + 2 + 2
```

But instead I get a

> ```
> Circular property definition: C=${A} +  ${B} + ${B} -> A=1 -> B=2 -> B=2 -> [Help 1]
> ```

**Question*8: What am I misunderstanding here?

I am currently looking over the documentation for the plugin more closely to see if I missed something obvious.

Comment: Why do you need a property file which you reads or write it?

Comment: For this project, I have a properties file that is read by the final product install.  It is loaded on multiple servers for various tests and configurations, but the installer file is the same.  When the properties change, we have to go modify the properties file on all servers to reflect the ne configuration.  I am making it a single point of change that all servers can grab and use.

Answer (score 3):

You encountered a bug of the `properties-maven-plugin`, which has already been [reported](https://github.com/mojohaus/properties-maven-plugin/issues/27) earlier this year, but fix is not yet part of a new release:

> Unwarranted "Circular property definition" #27

Indeed, having a simple `pom.xml` with the following content:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>read-install-properties</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <files>
                        <file>src/main/resources/build.properties</file>
                    </files>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>write-install-properties</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFile>target/build.properties</outputFile>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

With `src/main/resources/build.properties` having the simple content:

```
C = ${A} + ${B} + ${B}
```

And invoking Maven as:

```
mvn clean validate -DA=1 -DB=2
```

Would result in a

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (read-install-properties) on pr
oject sample: Circular property definition: C=${A} + ${B} + ${B} -> A=1 -> B=2 -> B=2 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The concerned component is the [`CircularDefinitionPreventer`](https://github.com/psenechal-stingray/properties-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/properties/CircularDefinitionPreventer.java) class and hasn't been fixed yet via the latest SNAPSHOT version of the plugin.

You can test it again as following: add to your pom file the section below:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>apache.snapshots</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And change the plugin version to `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. This will allow you to use the latest SNAPSHOT version of the plugin, however the fix hasn't been provided yet (at the time of writing).

---

The same issue is instead not present via [Maven filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). Having the following sample POM snippet:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Wit the same file as above and executing

```
mvn clean package -DA=1 -DB2
```

We would have as part of the generated `.jar` file the `build.properties` file with content:

```
C = 1 + 2 + 2
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I modified my project and all is well!

Comment: @david if that helped you out, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thanks.